# Exclude bad images from keras `image_dataset_from_directory`

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I wonder whether there is a way to excluse bad/corrupt images when reading images from a directory using `image_dataset_from_directory`. In the [tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/#filter-out-corrupted-images), it suggests deleting
those corrupt images but that's not what I want. I want to keep those images in the folder, but ignore them when Keras load them. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Build your dataloader manually using tf.data API or keras.utils.Sequence. The type of `image_dataset_from_directory` dataloader's functionality are limited.